# Doxygen is searching for files in unexpected directories

Tags: file, search, doxygen

I am a fairly new user of Doxygen and am using Doxygen 1.8.6 on a Win7 64bit.

I have specified a specific directory for the INPUT tag but i can see that doxygen is searching in other directories than this: - It searches in the directory where it is called from (same place as where my doxyfile is located) and at some higher level directories.

If I enable the "RECURSIVE" feature for the INPUT then it searches recursively in all the folders from where i call doxygen and up. This takes a lot of time, especially when it searches into the doxygen output directory which is a sub-directory to where i call doxygen from (and to where the doxyfile is located).

Doxygen is searching in these (to me) unexpected directories before it searches in the one specified by "INPUT" tag.

My directory structure is something like this:

- /build/product
- /build/productA/
- /build/productA/doxygen
- /build/productA/doxygen/doxyfile
- /build/productA/doxygen/output_dir/*
- /build/productB/
- /build/productB/doxygen
- /build/productB/doxygen/doxyfile
- /application/*
- /hal/*
- /service/*

This is not the behaviour i expected.

Is it correct behavior of Doxygen ?

Are there some feature that i should chagne ?

Thanks for you input

/Michael

Comment: This is unexpected so the most likely candidate is something wrong with the format of your INPUT line.  Can you share this, or part of it, with us?  Verbatim please, as punctuation on that line is important.

Comment: The INPUT line is as follows:
`INPUT                  = ../../../service/communication/`

Comment: (Previous now-deleted comment was in error). Is it definitely finding the correct folder as well as searching the unexpected set?  Either way I'm a bit puzzled.  How are you seeing that it is searching the doxygen folders?

Comment: I found the reason for my issue - it was a "misconfiguration" in my Doxyfile. I had set the EXCLUDE tag to exclude `../../../build/productA/doxygen/` and it seems like this forces doxygen to search at that "path" for files to exclude. I cleared my EXCLUDE tag and now it is running as expected.
After seeing the behavior and re-reading the comment for the EXCLUDE tag i now understand the feature behind it.


Thank you for your feedback - it made me analyze the Doxygen output another time and this time i got it :)

Comment: Glad to have been helpful.  One thing to watch on the INPUT line is that it is *space* separated.  Example text, e.g. for FILE_PATTERNS, suggests these lists are comma separated; that format doesn't work and can lead to confusing results - which is what I suspected your original problem related to.

Comment: PS.  It's useful to provide your discovery as an 'answer' - so this question does not continue to show as open / unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my issue - it was a "misconfiguration" in my Doxyfile.

I had set the EXCLUDE tag to exclude `../../../build/productA/doxygen/` and it seems like this forces doxygen to search at that "path" for files to exclude. I cleared my EXCLUDE tag and now it is running as expected.

After seeing the behavior and re-reading the comment for the EXCLUDE tag i now understand the feature behind it.